# Adding a column with consecutive numbers in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I apologize if this question is abhorrently simple, but I'm looking for a way to just add a column of consecutive integers to a data frame (if my data frame has 200 observations, for example, starting with 1 for the first observation, and ending with 200 on the last one).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25):

For a dataframe (df) you could use

```
df$observation <- 1:nrow(df)
```

but if you have a matrix you would rather want to use

```
ma <- cbind(ma, "observation"=1:nrow(ma))
```

as using the first option will transform your data into a list.

Source: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/adding-column-of-ordered-numbers-to-matrix-td2250454.html

Answer (score 14):

Or use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(observation = 1:n())
```

You might want it to be the first column of `df`.

```
df %>% mutate(observation = 1:n()) %>% select(observation, everything())
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, function [tibble::rowid_to_column](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html) is what you need if you are using *tidyverse* ecosystem.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(x=c(10, 20, 30), 
              y=c('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'))
dat %>% rowid_to_column(var='observation')

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  observation     x y    
        <int> <dbl> <chr>
1           1    10 alpha
2           2    20 beta 
3           3    30 gamma
```